# Under what conditions does ABC=AB'C imply B=B'?

Tags: linear-algebra

I am doing some linear algebra HW, and I am trying to prove the statement:
Let $\langle \textbf{x},\textbf{y}\rangle_B=\textbf{x}^TB\textbf{y}$, where $\textbf{x},\textbf{y}\in \mathbb{R}^n$. Then $B=B^T\iff\langle \textbf{x},\textbf{y}\rangle_B=\langle \textbf{y},\textbf{x}\rangle_B$.
In proving the reverse, I managed to show that $\textbf{x}^TB\textbf{y}=\textbf{x}^TB^T\textbf{y}$. However, I am unsure how to justify that $B=B^T$. Under what conditions does $ABC=AB'C$ imply $B=B'$? Thanks!

Comment: Note that $x^T A y = 0$ for all $x,y $ **iff** $A=0$.

Comment: @copper.hat thanks!